# Sorting for both numbers and alphabets in js

Tags: javascript, sorting, numbers, alphabetical

```
productID = '65,78,98,565,12,546,879,456123,456,987,1,312,45,8,546,123,0,165,4566'; productID = 'asd,sad,d,s,as,e,ew,qw,asd,xsad,sad,sad,asd,eqw,sda,ds,wqe,sda,sad,wqewq';


multipleProducts = productID.split(',').sort().sort(function(a, b){return a - b}); productID = multipleProducts.join(','); console.log(productID)
```

how much I can relay this js function can anyone find out or break out this function with any scenrio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
productID = '65,78,98,565,12,546,879,456123,456,987,1,312,45,8,546,123,0,165,4566'; productID2 = 'asd,sad,d,s,as,e,ew,qw,asd,xsad,sad,sad,asd,eqw,sda,ds,wqe,sda,sad,wqewq';


multipleProducts = productID.split(',').sort(sortNumbers).join(','); 
console.log(multipleProducts)
multipleProducts2 = productID2.split(',').sort(sortString).join(','); 
console.log(multipleProducts2)

function sortString(a, b){return a > b ? 1 : -1}
function sortNumbers(a,b){return (+a) > (+b) ? 1 : -1}
```

Comment: if i got the combination of numbers and string together...?

Comment: And how you want to sort it then? give me example input and the expected output

Comment: My input will be dynamic sometime it's may be numbers combination, alphabets combinations and mixed( alphabets + number ) combinations...
like  
'12,54,98,21456,1,456', 'do-test,noman,yousef,thanks' & 'abc,12,43,5454,21,bdf,a'
i wanna create a generic solutions that arrange this type of inputs in JS. after that same same technique will apply in php.

Comment: what output you want for the input `'abc,12,43,5454,21,bdf,a'`?

Comment: thanks, I used it and modify according to scenarios :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a sorting function which respects numbers and strings by converting the value to number, if the value [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite), otherwise take the string.

```js
const
    ASC = (a, b) => a > b || -(a < b)
    ASC_BY_TYPE = (...p) => ASC(...p.map(v => isFinite(v) ? +v : v));

var productID0 = '65,78,98,565,12,546,879,456123,456,987,1,312,45,8,546,123,0,165,4566',
    productID1 = 'asd,sad,d,s,as,e,ew,qw,asd,xsad,sad,sad,asd,eqw,sda,ds,wqe,sda,sad,wqewq';


console.log(productID0.split(',').sort(ASC_BY_TYPE).join());
console.log(productID1.split(',').sort(ASC_BY_TYPE).join());
```

Comment: it's work :). thank you